# Compile Bootstrap with LESS using Node with makefile

Tags: node.js, less, twitter-bootstrap

I have read the [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling) instructions but cannot get the files to compile. Is there a more detailed tutorial or can anyone put me right, thanks.

I open a terminal and enter

```
npm install less
```

This seems to install file, I then change directory to the root of my Bootstrap directory and enter

```
make
```

I get the following error:

```
`make` is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

Comment: what exactly are you having trouble with? you may need to install lessc as a global ( npm install -g less )

Comment: I have edited the question with more detail, thanks.

Comment: It seems like make isn't in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting just means `make` isn't installed.  Installation varies depending on what operating system you're running.  I would use a package manager, e.g. homebrew or macports for mac, apt-get for Ubuntu/Debian.

The command should look like:

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

On windows get:

> [less.js-windows](https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows)

Setup your paths correctly...
Then run:

> lessc bootstrap.less